# Unknown service: 'secretsmanager' or AWS Secrets Manager service is not in the list of AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I was trying to use AWS secrets manager service for storing secret keys. I could store the key in the secrets manager, but while retrieving the key using the code they provide I'm getting this error.

> UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'secretsmanager'. Valid service names are: acm, alexaforbusiness,...

I tried a search on the AWS CLI and the service is not on the list also.

```
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

acm                                      | alexaforbusiness                        
apigateway                               | application-autoscaling                 
appstream                                | appsync     
.
.
.
```

Do I need some kind of aws cli update? May be because of the CLI version that I'm using. 
Then, how can I update that. I tried

```
sudo apt-get install -y awscli
```

an it says

```
awscli is already the newest version (1.11.13-1ubuntu1~16.04.0).
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

secretsmanager is only available from aws cli version **[1.15.8](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/index.html)** and upwards

> aws --version
>
> aws-cli/1.15.10 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/17.5.0 botocore/1.10.10

You may need to [manually install/update aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html)

Comment: Indeed, I would recommend against the Ubuntu `aws` cli in the apt repository and use `pip` to install and upgrade.  Use the [Linux Install](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux.html) instructions to get your PATH set correctly.

Comment: If using boto3 and receving the same error, uprade to the latest version by pip install boto3 --upgrade

Comment: Does the AWS sdk present you w a message like "new version of the sdk is available? Like Microsoft does excessively?